# How do you get ValidateAntiForgeryToken to work via a NLB in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get ValidateAntiForgeryToken to work in asp.net core with an NLB.

In full .net I would set the machine keys to be the same but how do you do this in .net core?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the DataProtection service

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"))
                .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
```

Comment: We removed machine key because it was impossible to rotate without downtime. You can also use AD, azure blob storage and redis are coming soon and even write your own store should you want to use a database.